# Module 'websockets' has no attribute 'client'

Tags: python, html

I am running, in Jupyter Notebook with Anaconda Navigator, a code in python that uses the "requests_html" library, and this error has occurred:
"AttributeError: module 'websockets' has no attribute 'client'"
I already have installed the websocks-client package, but still occurs.

```
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession
asession = AsyncHTMLSession()

r = await asession.get('https://python.org/')
await r.html.arender(timeout=15)
resp = r.html.raw_html
print(resp)
```

Comment: Sharing the exception including the stack trace should help you get an answer. I'd also share the Python version and the requirements.txt or appropriate dependency file.

Answer (score 3):

Explicitly importing the 'client' before running my code fixed this issue for me (I did not test code given in original post).

from websockets import client

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

This was patched in the latest version of pyppeteer, make sure you have the latest version.  There is a [pull request](https://github.com/pyppeteer/pyppeteer/commit/6320c084e4586960a4622d7cfefd44c2dea108a5) that hasn't been merged yet to allow support for `websockets 10`.  If you simply install the latest version of pyppeteer, then you will be left with `websockets 9`.  I need `websockets 10` for other modules so I installed pyppeteer using the following command and this fixed the `requests_html` error.

```
pip install -U git+https://github.com/pyppeteer/pyppeteer@dev
```

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else works, try to delete "websocket" folder from "python/site-packages/" folder.

When I did it, my IDE (PyCharm) asked me if I want to install package "websocket", then "websocket-client" and after I clicked "yes" downloaded them automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I had to downgrade to websockets 8.1

```
pip install websockets==8.1
```

Worked afterwards.